# How to apply Sticky Table header design on every ajax refresh which is every 30 seconds?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jsp

I am following this [tutorial](http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/StickyTableHeaders/index3.html) for jquery Sticky Table Header design. And I am able to make this work and it works fine.

By Sticky Table Header I mean - I will be able to move `table header column` and `table row header` if I am scrolling right on my table or if I am scrolling down just as shown in the above tutorial example.

Here is my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/659zm/17/) which is using the same idea and has all my jquery and ajax refresh call as well. In my jsfiddle, you won't be able to see the how the page looks like after the refresh as I am not able to find a way to show the page after refresh in jsfiddle. In general, I have a simple static JSP page which has the same html as shown in the jsfiddle and I am just refreshing the container div every 30 seconds.

As I added one more feature, which is to refresh the `container div` every 30 seconds (part of jsfiddle example). And my refresh is working fine but what happens after refresh is -

- I always see a gap between last row and scrollable bar (see below image).
- Secondly, sticky table header feature doesn't work as well on the refresh somehow.

I am suspecting this is happening because of my css issue or I need to init some js.

Below is my `testingstick.jsp` code -

```
<body>
    <div class="container">     
        <div class="component">

            <table id="tabDes" style=''>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Machine Name</th>
                        <th>Fresh Data 95</th>
                        <th>Fresh Data 99</th>
                        <th>Data Hello</th>
                        <th>Data World</th>
                        <th>Average</th>
                        <th>Status Server</th>
                        <th>Workflow</th>                           
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <th>machineA</th>
                        <td>52</td>
                        <td>40</td>
                        <td>9</td>
                        <td>47</td>
                        <td>31</td>
                        <td>UP</td>
                        <td>NONE</td>                           
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>  
    </div><!-- /container -->
</body>
```

Any thoughts how can I avoid these issues? You can use my jsfiddle as shown above to built this locally to reproduce this problem.

Here is an image which looks like after the refresh and you can see clearly that there is a gap coming between last row and scroller and also sticky table header doesn't work -

[image]

**NOTE:-**

I am working with JSP and Spring Controller so I am passing data from Controller to JSP and then I am using Ajax refresh to refresh the page so that updated data gets shown automatically. But to understand my question, I have hardcoded the values in the Table which in general is coming from Controller.

**UPDATE:-**

After ajax refresh, this is what I get back in `data` as I logged into console as `console.log(data)` and from this I am extracting container div.

```
GET http://localhost:8080/p13nzookweb/testingstick.jsp

200 OK
        115ms   
jquery.min.js (line 5)

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<link href="/ressvr/v/4m5ts2dj2y1pdj0yoexr5fvh5yx.css?debug=true&showRaw=true" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Testing Stickness</title>
<style>
.red {
    color: #ff0000;
    font-weight: bold;
}
</style>

<!-- CSS Stuff -->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-throttle-debounce/1.1/jquery.ba-throttle-debounce.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/StickyTableHeaders/js/jquery.stickyheader.js"></script>


<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
    // Create overlay and append to body:
    $('<div id="overlay"/>').css({
        position: 'fixed',
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        width: '100%',
        height: $(window).height() + 'px',
        opacity:0.4, 
        background: 'lightgray url(http://bradsknutson.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/page-loader.gif) no-repeat center'
    }).hide().appendTo('body');

    // Execute refresh with interval:
    setInterval(refresh, 30 * 1000);
});

//Create a refresh function:
function refresh(){
    // SHOW overlay
    $('#overlay').show();
    // Retrieve data:
    $.ajax({
        url: 'testingstick.jsp',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
            // onSuccess take only the container content
            var content =  $($.parseHTML(data)).filter(".container"); 
            //Replace content inside the div
            $('.container').html(content);
            // HIDE the overlay:
            $('#overlay').hide();
        }
    });
}

</script>

</head>

<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="component">
            <table class="overflow-y">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Machine Name</th>
                        <th>Fresh Data 95</th>
                        <th>Fresh Data 99</th>
                        <th>Data Hello</th>
                        <th>Data World</th>
                        <th>Average</th>
                        <th>Status Server</th>
                        <th>Workflow1111111111</th>
                        <th>Workflow1222222</th>
                        <th>Workflow23333333</th>
                        <th>Workflow34444444444444</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <th>machineA</th>
                        <td>52</td>
                        <td>40</td>
                        <td>9</td>
                        <td>47</td>
                        <td>31</td>
                        <td>UP</td>
                        <td>NONE</td>
                        <td>YES</td>
                        <td>NO</td>
                        <td>YUP</td>                                                                        
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>

testingstick (line 46)
```

I am using this javascript - `<script src="http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/StickyTableHeaders/js/jquery.stickyheader.js"></script>` which is adding all the extra stickness in the table so I am thinking because of automatic refresh it is getting disabled which means I need to init something after refresh I guess..

Comment: The jsfiddle doesn't work. If your code needs AJAX request, link to a page of your server, or post the AJAX response, or better both.

Comment: I didn't see any issue in Chrome. What browser are you seeing this in?

Comment: @ChrisSobolewski: I am also using Chrome. If I don't use Ajax Refresh and just keep on pressing F5 on the browser, it does work fine. But instead of refreshing manually, I added an ajax refresh which refreshes the page automatically for me as I am loading only container div and then sticky part doesn't work for me and also I see a gap between last row and scroller.

Comment: @Oriol: Server link is internal, you won't be able to access it. I guess to reproduce this issue, you might want to build it locally in a jsp and then add ajax refresh on the div container as I have done in my jsfiddle..

Comment: @AKIWEB your jsfiddle does not work because the requested page does not exist on the jsfiddle.net site..

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli: How do I add the code so that it can get refreshed automatically for me in jsfiddle? Is there any way to do that in jsfidddle? Bcoz currently in jsfiddle it just keeps on refreshing and image is shown always.. And not sure how to make that work in jsfiddle.

Comment: Edited the question with my ajax response..

Comment: @AKIWEB, posted an answer.. hope it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay,

the main issue is that the code in the tutorial does not result in some plugin that is reusable.

It is code that runs once on DOM ready, that does its stuff altering the DOM and finishes.. There is no API to re-run/update or do anything with it..

So I wrapped that code inside a function and called that instead of including the .js file (*which runs once*).

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/AybKj/ (*with some changes to work around the ajax limitation*)

---

*basically I create a function `pluginCode` which contains the whole script from the tutorial, and run it once at DOM ready, and then at the end of each AJAX call to re-set the table.*)

Comment: Thanks a lot Gaby. So in short I just need to use the `pluginCode` right? And everything you have kept as it is? And I will be placing that pluginCode inside the script tag?

Comment: yep.. those are the changes that matter to you .. the rest was to make the jsfiddle work..

Comment: And also do I need to include the js or not now? As currently I am including this js `<script src="http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/StickyTableHeaders/js/jquery.stickyheader.js"></script>` Or the code you have added will work if I remove this inclusion of script?

Comment: It will work, without it, since all the code has gone inside the `pluginCode` function. (*i have removed the link to the file in the fiddle i posted*)